# Getting dimensions of background-image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, background-image

I'm trying to get width and height of element's background-image. When you click on it, it should show it inside the element ("200 300" in this case).

HTML:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x300);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#test').on('click', function () {
  $(this).text(getDimensions($(this)));
});

var getDimensions = function(item) {
  var img = new Image(); //Create new image
  img.src = item.css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, ''); //Source = clicked element background-image
  return img.width + ' ' + img.height; //Return dimensions
};
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Emeraldar/62s5k/). The problem is it works **only in Chrome**, all the other main browsers return "0 0". I have no idea what's the reason. Isn't that graphic fully loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that some browsers add quotes to the CSS, and it was trying to load (in the fiddle's case) "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/%22http://placehold.it/200x300%22". I've updated your .replace() to look for " as well, and a fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/4uMEq/

```
$('#test').on('click', function () {
    $(this).text(getDimensions($(this)));
});

var getDimensions = function (item) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = item.css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$|"/ig, '');
    return img.width + ' ' + img.height;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd never have guessed that was the problem.

Comment: When in doubt, open the web inspector and `console.log()` ;) What tipped me off was that FF was failing to load an image with that strange URL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to wait for `onload` event on image.